# Toggle button with conditional mouse over effect

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a toggle button like this:

```
<ToggleButton Name="pptSlide_ON_OFF"
              IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.SlideExcluded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"
              Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"
              Background="Transparent"
              Command="{Binding DataContext.SlideOnOffCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}">
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="bg">
                <Image x:Name ="pptSlide_ON_OFF_image">
                    <Image.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SlideExcluded}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Import Icons Eye OFF.png"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SlideExcluded}" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Import Icons Eye.png"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="pptSlide_ON_OFF_image" Property="Source" Value="/MouseOver.png" />
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed"  Value ="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

I would like to have a conditional 'IsMouseOver' trigger if possible, such that when button is not toggled, on mouse over, base image changes to some other image (MouseOver.png) like it is now, and then when it is toggled, to change to a different image (MouseOver2.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MultiTrigger`. I stripped some of your implementation specifics from the example, but the principle should be clear:

```
<ToggleButton.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="bg">
            <Image x:Name ="pptSlide_ON_OFF_image" Source="/Image1.png">
            </Image>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="pptSlide_ON_OFF_image" Property="Source" Value="/Image2.png"/>
            </MultiTrigger>

            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="pptSlide_ON_OFF_image" Property="Source" Value="/Image3.png"/>
            </MultiTrigger>

            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="pptSlide_ON_OFF_image" Property="Source" Value="/Image4.png"/>
            </MultiTrigger>


            <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed"  Value ="True">
                <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ToggleButton.Template>
```

Comment: You know, actually I created a sample project and more or less 1:1 copied my tested result into this answer. If it is not working for you, then it's highly likely that you use it in a way that introduces secondary problems... You can edit your question with new details about your implementation and an exact description of how it doesn't work. Then I can re-visit and improve my answer.

Comment: it works actually! This button is the part of the list of the buttons and it was bound to some property in back-end that I was unnecessarily refreshing. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I just have one additional question. What if in addition to changing the image of this toggle button, I also want to change an image of some other button, depending on conditions of this button in code above? I tried to simply add another 'setter' line with the target name of the image of the other button but it gives the compilation error.

Comment: The `ControlTemplate.Triggers` are only meant to modify the contents of the current `ControlTemplate`. If you want to modify anything external, you need a different approach with binding and converters or style-triggers, depending on the details. Ask a separate question if you can't figure it out from those few keywords.

Comment: ok, I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544065/toggle-button-to-change-the-property-of-some-other-button

Comment: @Ivan impressive speed, reading into binding, converters, style-triggers, trying to use those things in order to solve your problem, determining you need help on the topic, formulating a question - all cramped into 13 minutes. To be honest, I feel like you skipped basically every single step of this list and just created a relatively cheap copy-paste question. Sorry if I mis-judged this.

Comment: if I understood correctly, the problem is that I copy-pasted your answer from here and put it in my new question. It wasn't my intention to claim it as my own, I just wanted to get a quick answer to the other question. I will be glad to cite you in my other question, just don't know how.

Comment: No, its perfectly fine to copy-paste my code. Just you should create a new question in a way that it is focused on the new problem. My code is focused on the question here, so it is just not suitable to be placed 1:1 into the new question.

Comment: ok, got it. thanks for pointing that out and I'll try to edit other question.

Answer (score 3):

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="TButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="35" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Name="OuterBorder" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0" >
                        <Border Name="InnerBorder" BorderThickness="2">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{StaticResource ButtonSingleTrigger}" />
                            <!--<Setter Property="Style" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{StaticResource ButtonOuterBHover}" />-->
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultState}" />
                            <!--<Setter Property="Style" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{StaticResource ButtonOuterBHover}" />-->
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{StaticResource ButtonSingleTrigger}" />

                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="true" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{StaticResource ButtonMultiTrigger}" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```