# Toggle button to change the property of some other button

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a toggle button which changes its image base based on whether it is checked and mouse over effect. Now, in addition to this, I want to also change the image base of some other external button, every time the button above is checked/unchecked. I assume I have to bind this button to the events of the above button, just don't know exactly how.

Comment: Your question should contain the *"other external button"* as some xaml example code, then it becomes easier to show the necessary steps in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the "above" button an `x:Name`:

...and use a `MultiDataTrigger` or a `DataTrigger` in your `ControlTemplate`:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=above}" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="pptSlide_ON_OFF_image" Property="Source" Value="/Image4.png"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```